# ImportError: cannot import name 'AlbertModel' from 'transformers' - Bert summarizer

Tags: python, bert-language-model, summarize, summarization, spacy-transformers

I'm trying to summarize some text with "Text Summarization with BERT" by next steps:
first, installation of:

```
 pip install transformers==2.2.0
 pip install bert-extractive-summarizer
```

secondly,import summarizer:

```
 from summarizer import Summarizer,TransformerSummarizer
```

and thenI got a importError like that: cannot import name 'AlbertModel' from 'transformers'

my reference: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/text-summarization-using-bert-gpt2-xlnet-5ee80608e961

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [**full text** of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), *as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install transformers --upgrade
pip install torch
```

might solve it